# Size of Python List from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am having concerns about the Python List size... like how many elements or how much size it can hold ?

My requirement is to merge the multiple JSON files from s3 into single compressed file from AWS Lambda with Python3.9 as runtime

Here I am reading the contents from each file by get_object boto3 function and appending it in List inside a loop and once I appended all the json object in the list then I will compress(gzip) and put it (put_object) into another s3 folder

```
def file_read():
    data = []
    for f in s3_files:
        s3_data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket = <'Bucket name'>,Key = <'Bucket key'>)
        data.append(s3_data['Body'].read().decode("utf-8"))
    .....
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket = <'Bucket name'>, Body = data ,Key = <'Bucket key'>)
```

Since no option is available to append the contents in s3...I am appending in list and writing it in s3 and upto now the combines file size not exceeding 2- 3 mb and it works fine but in future during peak hours 7 -10 gb (combined file size and 11500 elements) is expected

In that case my question is will my python List (data = []) can works fine and able to append all the json objects and write it to the file in s3 ?

Please advice or tell me any other good way to handle the high load interms of list size and also I am aware that list size is depends on the memory size which we allocates in AWS lambda so the max memory can allocate is 10240 MB so by increasing the memory to 10000 MB can handle this LIST size issues ?

Comment: I would propose to use "streaming", which in theory is just reading and writing a few bytes at a time, which means that you could process two 10GB files with just 64MB of memory. S3 allows this by just reading and writing (byte) ranges. The tricky part is, that JSON itself is not particular well-suited for that task (a minor fix for this is JSONL). How well this approach works depends on your data structure in JSON.

Comment: Is your goal to simply merge multiple files into one file? What do the files contain -- is it normal text, or CSV data, or perhaps binary data? How big is each file? Also, you mention that you are concerned about "future peak hours" -- given that an AWS Lambda function can only run for a maximum of 15 minutes, do you see this as a problem or is the process quite quick? If you are continually combining files, it might be better to use EC2 than Lambda.

Comment: Each file will be less than 100 kb and each file contains json objects and also I can see for my lambda current taking approx 45 seconds for 150 plus files which is almost 3 mb

Comment: I agree with @JohnRotenstein that it depends on a lot of factors, but let's say for instance your if your size exceeds 10 Gb then Lambda would fail therefore it would be safe to use EC2 as a long term and scalable approach for such heavy memory intensive tasks

Comment: Consider using AWS Kenesis streams with AWS lambda to merge s3 files.

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer since lambda will have timeout issues I have planned to run my code from aws Ecs fargate container so in that time will not be the problem but what about the list? Whether it can able to load that many objects (nearly 10gb size) ?

Comment: Yes, under the condition that you are using 4 vCPU since it allows you to allocate memory ranging from 8GB to 30 GB

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer so If i set my CPU value to 4vcpu's then my list can withstand more than 10GB load isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, If you set your CPU value to 4vCPU then you can set your memory to a higher value like 15GB or 20 GB or 30GB, thus your list can be processed